# Making a df of p values from logistic regressions?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I have many univariate logistic regressions, and I would like to find a way to make a df of the outputs (Estimate, Std. Error, p value etc.) other than just copying by hand. I've figured out how to make a table of the AIC values (package `AICcmodavg`), but not the others- is there a way to incorporate more outputs into the AICtab? Also if someone has a hand way of running univariate logistic regression across many columns in a dataset rather than doing them each one by one...

```
library(AICcmodavg)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

diamonds<-diamonds

#a few example log. regressions
CP<-glm(price~cut, data = diamonds) 
summary(CP)

DP<-glm(price~depth, data = diamonds) 
summary(DP)

ClP<-glm(price~clarity, data = diamonds) 
summary(ClP)

#AIC table
bestmodels<-list(CP, DP, ClP)
bestmodel_names<-c("Cut", "Depth", "Clarity")
aic<-aictab(cand.set = bestmodels, modnames = bestmodel_names)
aic<-aic%>%
  rename(Model=Modnames)
```

Comment: There are a lot of questions on SO about how to run univariate regressions on columns of a data set; I would write an answer but it might duplicate those too much.  For the rest of your question, something like `purrr::map_dfr(bestmodels, broom::tidy)` will get you most of the way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```r
## select everything except the response variable
predvars <- setdiff(names(diamonds), "price")
## run all the regressions
rlist <- map(predvars,
             function(v) lm(reformulate(v, resp = "price"), diamonds)
             ## set names for `.id` arg of map_dfr
         ) |> setNames(predvars)
## run `tidy()` on each model, identify results by pred var (name of list element)
purrr::map_dfr(rlist, 
               broom::tidy, .id = "predvar") |>
    ## probably not interested in the intercepts
    filter(term != "(Intercept)")
```

Comment: prob so simple but- how would i modify this code to then run all possible combinations of these variables?

Comment: if you want all possible combinations (maybe not a good idea!) you can use `MuMIn::dredge()`, or more efficiently, the `leaps` package

Comment: Note that the `diamonds` data set has 9 possible predictor variables, so 2^9 = 512 possible subset models (including the null model) - what are you planning to do with them all ... ?